# Selenium work around 'TimeoutException' is not defined?

Tags: python, selenium

I want to **work around** the **TimeOutException in Python Selenium.**

This happens:

```
1.) Open Browser, Call URL
2.) Trying to find Element
2.1) Works sometimes
2.2) Works not sometimes and throws TimeoutException
3.) Should look for other elements
```

I can never reach step `3.)` after we have hit the exception in `2.2)` and try/catch does not work.

After step `3.)` there are many other steps. How can I let the program flow around this timeout. It is timeouting when the element is not there.

**Code**

```py
    def getByClass(InputElement, driver):
        getByClass = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, InputElement)))
        return getByClass

    try:
        element = Dom.getByClass('test-class', driver).text
    except TimeoutException:
        element = 'element not found'
    print(element)
```

**Result**

```py
    except TimeoutException:
    NameError: name 'TimeoutException' is not defined
```

Comment: Add the code here.

Comment: I added the code now.

Answer (score 15):

I can't see your import statements from your sample, so make sure you have

`from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException`
 at the top of your `.py` file.

Answer (score 4):

Import the `TimeoutException` from selenium exceptions like this:

```py
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
```

Put the Function inside the try block itself:

```py
try:
    getByClass = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, InputElement)))
    element = Dom.getByClass('test-class', driver).text
except TimeoutException:
    element = 'element not found'
print(element)
```

Comment: A tip, if you are under a range, is to call up a generator. So you can start it all over again and don´t stop the project you are in.